# JSTree creating duplicate nodes when loading data with create_node

Tags: jstree

I'm having an issue when I'm trying to load my initial data for JSTree; I have 2 top level nodes attached to the root node but when I load them it looks like the last node added is being duplicated within JSTree. At first it looked as if it was my fault for not specifically declaring a new object each time but I've fixed that. I'm using .net MVC so the initial data is coming from the model that is passed to my view (that is the data passed into the data parameter of the method).

```
this.loadInitialData = function (data) {
    var tree = self.getTree();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var node = new Object();
        node.id = data[i].Id;
        node.parent = data[i].Parent;
        node.text = data[i].Text;
        node.state = {
            opened: data[i].State.Opened,
            disabled: data[i].State.Disabled,
            selected: data[i].State.Selected
        };
        node.li_attr = { "node-type": data[i].NodeType };
        node.children = [];

        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].Children.length; j++) {
            var childNode = new Object();
            childNode.id = data[i].Children[j].Id;
            childNode.parent = data[i].Children[j].Parent;
            childNode.text = data[i].Children[j].Text;
            childNode.li_attr = { "node-type": data[i].Children[j].NodeType };
            childNode.children = data[i].Children[j].HasChildren;

            node.children.push(childNode);
        }

        tree.create_node("#", node, "last");
    }
}
```

My initial code was declaring node like the following:

```
var node = {
    id: data[i].Id
}
```

I figured that was the cause of what I'm seeing but fixing it has not changed anything. Here is what is happening when I run the application; on the first pass of the method everything looks like it is working just fine.

[image: JSTree on the first pass]

But after the loop is run for the second (and last) time here is the final result.

[image: JSTree final result]

It looks like the node objects are just a copy of each other, but when I run the code through the debugger I see the object being initialized each time. Does anyone have an idea what would cause this behavior in JSTree? Should I be using a different method to create my initial nodes besides create_node?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue; I didn't realize but I was setting my id property to the same id for both node groups. After I fixed it everything started working as expected.

Comment: Please can you explain your answer because i have issues when copy tree from one page to another :(